# Writing a Test Class for sendMail

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

The following code is working correctly in my sandbox but I'm not sure how to write a test class to correctly test it after reading documentation, can anyone provide any clues?

```
global class Scheduled_Email_Report Implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        sendmail();
    }

    public void sendmail()
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email =
Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate('00X5800000139sW', '0035800000qoLad', 
null);

        Messaging.sendEmail(New Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all? Done any research? If you don't know how to even begin, **[Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing)** is a much better platform. This question just reads like a request for the community to do your work for you without any good faith effort on your part to learn.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are many answers on how to test schedulables. Those involve querying for the chron job class both before `test.StartTest()` and after `test.EndTest()` whether the job has been executed and asserting the results. See [Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm?search_text=cron) for an example unit test.

There are a couple of different ways of testing email sends that aren't inherently obvious. Both involve using the [Limits Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm#apex_methods_system_limits). There are two different techniques in particular that apply with one being more specific than the other.

**getEmailInvocations()**

- Returns the number of email invocations (such as sendEmail) that have been called.

**getLimitEmailInvocations()**

- Returns the total number of email invocation (such as sendEmail) that can be called.

By using the above methods, you can check for the number of email invocations available and the number that have been called *before* the email send. Then, check again *after* the send. You should be able to assert that the limit is now one less than it was before the email send was made.

Sending an email is also consider a DML operation which means the following limit checks also apply:

**getDMLRows()**

- Returns the number of records that have been processed with any statement that counts against DML limits, such as DML statements, the Database.emptyRecycleBin method, and other methods.

**getLimitDMLRows()**

- Returns the total number of records that can be processed with any statement that counts against DML limits, such as DML statements, the database.EmptyRecycleBin method, and other methods.

**getDMLStatements()**

- Returns the number of DML statements (such as insert, update or the database.EmptyRecycleBin method) that have been called.

**getLimitDMLStatements()**

- Returns the total number of DML statements or the database.EmptyRecycleBin methods that can be called.

Just as with the getEmailInvocations() methods, you can use similar techniques with any of the above to make your before and after calls to set up the assertion that email was sent.